# C#. Doc to PDF conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I'm trying to convert doc or docx file to PDF using visual studio 2013. C# language. 
I tried to debug and I think I have problem with the following part of code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Count() > 1)
        {
            translate.ConvertAllWordFilesToPdf(args[0], args[1]);
        }

    }
```

I don't get any errors. I get this output message:
The program '[9240] Conversion.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Thank you for any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace Conversion
{
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Count() > 1)
        {
            translate.ConvertAllWordFilesToPdf(args[0], args[1]);
        }

    }

    public class translate
    {

        public static void ConvertAllWordFilesToPdf(string WordFilesLocation, string PdfFilesLocation)
        {
            Document doc = null;


            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = null;

            try
            {

                word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();


                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(WordFilesLocation);

                FileInfo[] wordFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.doc");

                if (wordFiles.Length > 0)
                {
                    word.Visible = false;
                    word.ScreenUpdating = false;
                    string sourceFile = "";
                    string destinationFile = "";
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (FileInfo wordFile in wordFiles)
                        {

                            Object filename = (Object)wordFile.FullName;

                            sourceFile = wordFile.Name;
                            destinationFile = "";


                            doc = word.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref oMissing,
                                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                            doc.Activate();
                            object outputFileName = null;

                            if (wordFile.FullName.ToUpper().Contains(".DOCX"))
                            {
                                outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");
                                destinationFile = sourceFile.Replace(".docx", ".pdf");

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                outputFileName = wordFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
                                destinationFile = sourceFile.Replace(".doc", ".pdf");
                            }

                            sourceFile = WordFilesLocation + @"C:\Source" + destinationFile;
                            destinationFile = PdfFilesLocation + @"C:\Destination" + destinationFile;

                            object fileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;


                            doc.SaveAs(ref outputFileName,
                                ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);


                            object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                            ((_Document)doc).Close(ref saveChanges, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                            doc = null;


                            if (System.IO.File.Exists(destinationFile))
                            {
                                System.IO.File.Replace(sourceFile, destinationFile, null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine("Success:" + "SourceFile-" + outputFileName.ToString() + " DestinationFile-" + destinationFile);

                        }


                        ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                        word = null;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Fail:" + "SourceFile-" + sourceFile + "  DestinationFile-" + destinationFile + "#Error-" + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error occured while processing");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (doc != null)
                {
                    ((_Document)doc).Close(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    doc = null;

                }
                if (word != null)
                {
                    ((_Application)word).Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    word = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow it down a bit?  What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: You tagged this as `asp.net` yet you are using Office Interop. These do not work well together. Microsoft [specifically recommends against it](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/257757). You are likely to run into all sorts of issues if you continue using the Interop libraries in an ASP.NET environment.

Comment: Don't convert doc to pdf. Does't show any result.

Comment: Are you actually passing the required arguments to the main method.

Comment: Thangadurai, how to pass the arguments?

Comment: Also, using Word Interop on the server has not been recommended for almost two decades by MS. The threading model is completeley wrong and can lead to poor server performance, or even de-stabalize the server.  MS doesn't recommend installing Office on the server for use in this scenario, and it also is a potential attack vector.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a very interesting piece of code:

```
sourceFile = WordFilesLocation + @"C:\Source" + destinationFile;
destinationFile = PdfFilesLocation + @"C:\Destination" + destinationFile;
```

Try remove the `@"C:\Source"`.
I removed it and the code worked on my computer.

Also, I'm not sure whether you should append a `@"\"` for some location strings (not ending with a "\"). Be careful.

Comment: The "@" symbol tells the compiler to escape all chars in the given string. It is not necessary at all, but you may need to modify the content of the string accordingly if you don't use it.

Comment: Instead of @"C:\Source" I put "\\" But it still doesn't work.

Comment: I get this output message: The program '[9240] Conversion.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: That's normal exit. I guess no file was processed. Try to output the args, length of wordFiles, wordFile.Name in the `foreach` loop etc. to locate the problem.